# New Blank Activity Android Application Not Working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm just getting started with Android application development and am following Android's [**Getting Started**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) documentation. I followed the steps and got to the point where you **finish your blank activity application**. When I hit finish it started working and there were different things going on according to the notifier on the bottom right of Eclipse, but now it has been **stuck** on **"Adjusting Android Project Classpath"** for about an hour. Does it just take forever to compile, or did I do something wrong? **Thanks!**
[image]

Comment: what is your compliace level .. Project-Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level

Comment: I tried to check so I had to end the process because it wouldn't let me close the window. Brought it back up and when I click on Project/Properties nothing happens.

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens??

Comment: Literally nothing happens at all. It just closes the toolbar and no window pops up.

Comment: On closer inspection "Properties" is greyed out which I take to mean it is disabled for some reason.

Comment: Did you install java and add the class path??

Comment: Java is installed, could you explain how to add a class path and what that means? Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geong9J5fDc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add a Class Path. Thank you Rob_Algonquin.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my workspace. Previously it was in Onedrive. I just moved the workspace to D: drive and restarted eclipse. That worked for me!